# How to trace all HTTP requests in .net core 2.1 globally?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, system.diagnostics

I want to log all HTTP requests in a dotnet core 2.1 application. Logging should include HTTP headers, body and the host address. I need to bind my logging code globally without changing the existing code.

I tried this example https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/capturing-and-tracing-all-http-requests-in-c-and-net/, but no HTTP event came to the Listener.

Is there any way to listen to HTTP events on dotnet core 2.1 globally?

Comment: Are you hosting on IIS? Can you enable the logging there?

Comment: @ste-fu It works on a container that I have no access

Comment: You can use a [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: You must create an instance of that `HttpEventListener` class referenced in your example. I have used this method in the past and works great, also for .NET Core.

Comment: @bartbje I did, but no events came to OnEventWritten method. Which version did you used? Is it possible .NET core 2.1 lack this feature? ( as mentioned here https://medium.com/criteo-labs/c-in-process-clr-event-listeners-with-net-core-2-2-ef4075c14e87 )

Comment: @cengaver, just to be clear, that article describes a way to log outgoing HTTP traffic, not incoming. Are you looking to log incoming, or outgoing?

Comment: @bartbje outgoing traffic. I also need to log the response

Comment: @cengaver, they did not remove it, as Application Insights for example, is able to capture this traffic without modifying the existing application. [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/develop/Src/DependencyCollector/Shared/Implementation/FrameworkHttpEventListener.cs) is the source code, might help you out. - updated the url to the actual EventListener.

Comment: @cengaver, these type of EventListeners will not provide you with the headers and body details, as these are not part of the event. I guess the only options for that would depend on how you do the request. Assuming you use `HttpClient` check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#outgoing-request-middleware) out. It might require slight modification of your application though.

Answer (score 13):

[This is a good blog post](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging) on HttpClient logging in .Net Core 2.1 by Steve Gordon.

In essence, you need to set the logging level of System.Net.Http.HttpClient to Trace to get detailed information about requests and response.

A sample of the required section in your appsettings.json is below:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Trace"
    }
  }
```

This will show all trace logging for all HttpClient requests and responses.

Comment: This does nothing at all

Comment: Is your logging configured correctly? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: There is something else that needs to be set in the code.. I always forget before this will work ... so annoying cause this is the best solution instead of middleware.. I have every thing setup and console logging.. but it doesnt show the http client traces.. what was needed.. a stupid little line of code

Comment: Apparently in NET6 there's a new way - https://josef.codes/asp-net-core-6-http-logging-log-requests-responses - but have to set in appsetting `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"` I dont know why your solution does not work in my new project,, when my old project migrated to net6 logs all the requests this way..

Answer (score 4):

You can log all http request informations in middleware. Take a look at the example below

1.Create a class `RequestHandlerMiddleware.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Onsolve.ONE.WebApi.Middlewares
{
    public sealed class RequestHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public RequestHandlerMiddleware(ILogger<RequestHandlerMiddleware> logger, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            logger.LogInformation($"Header: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Request.Headers, Formatting.Indented)}");

            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            var body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            logger.LogInformation($"Body: {body}");
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

            logger.LogInformation($"Host: {context.Request.Host.Host}");
            logger.LogInformation($"Client IP: {context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}");
            await next(context);
        }

    }
}
```

2.Add `RequestHandlerMiddleware` to `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseMiddleware<RequestHandlerMiddleware>();
```

or simpler

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"Header: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Request.Headers, Formatting.Indented)}");

        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        var body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        logger.LogInformation($"Body: {body}");
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

        logger.LogInformation($"Host: {context.Request.Host.Host}");
        logger.LogInformation($"Client IP: {context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}");
        await next.Invoke();
    });
}
```

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: So this will log outgoing http calls from his application? How does the middleware plug into clients, such as HttpClient?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it's only log the incoming requests. You want to log calls from HttpClient, right?

Comment: OP has stated in comments that he wants to log outgoing traffic, not incoming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Observer design pattern and the hooks provided by .NET to observe all http requests.

- DiagnosticSource
- EventSource

[This is a good blog post](https://www.meziantou.net/observing-all-http-requests-in-a-dotnet-application.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Since the other answers to this question either didn't work for me or seemed too complex to use, I will post my ASP.NET Core 8 WebAPI solution, which logs all REST requests.

First, `AddHttpLogging` must configure which HTTP fields to log, followed by  `UseHttpLogging` to enable the configured settings:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        // Add HTTP logging, log all HTTP fields.
        builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
        { 
            logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
        });

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.UseHttpLogging();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if(app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        // Use the configured HTTP logging.
        app.UseHttpLogging();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Next appsettings.json (Or appsettings.development.json) must configure the logging level to capture:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

This Microsoft Devblog [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-4/#http-logging-middleware) explains the subject in more details.

Answer (score -1):

Tried below easier solution which worked without tampering with final response flow

Create middleware class to intercept all requests and responses. Enable middleware class association in startup.cs

```
app.UseMiddleware<HttpRequestResponseLogger>();
```

Implement a middleware class to intercept request and response . optionally you can store these logs in a database. I am ignoring secrets and unnecessary header values

```
 public class HttpRequestResponseLogger
{
    RequestDelegate next;

    public HttpRequestResponseLogger(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
    //can not inject as a constructor parameter in Middleware because only Singleton services can be resolved
    //by constructor injection in Middleware. Moved the dependency to the Invoke method
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IHttpLogRepository repoLogs)
    {
        HttpLog logEntry = new HttpLog();
        await RequestLogger(context, logEntry);
        
        await next.Invoke(context);

        await ResponseLogger(context, logEntry);

        //store log to database repository
        repoLogs.SaveLog(logEntry);
    }

    // Handle web request values
    public async Task RequestLogger(HttpContext context, HttpLog log)
    {
        string requestHeaders = string.Empty;

        log.RequestedOn = DateTime.Now;
        log.Method = context.Request.Method;
        log.Path = context.Request.Path;
        log.QueryString = context.Request.QueryString.ToString();
        log.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType;

        foreach (var headerDictionary in context.Request.Headers)
        {
            //ignore secrets and unnecessary header values
            if (headerDictionary.Key != "Authorization" && headerDictionary.Key != "Connection" &&
                headerDictionary.Key != "User-Agent" && headerDictionary.Key != "Postman-Token" &&
                headerDictionary.Key != "Accept-Encoding")
            {
                requestHeaders += headerDictionary.Key + "=" + headerDictionary.Value + ", ";
            }
        }

        if (requestHeaders != string.Empty)
            log.Headers = requestHeaders;

        //Request handling. Check if the Request is a POST call 
        if (context.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            var body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            log.Payload = body;
        }
    }

    //handle response values
    public async Task ResponseLogger(HttpContext context, HttpLog log)
    {
        using (Stream originalRequest = context.Response.Body)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    context.Response.Body = memStream;
                    // All the Request processing as described above 
                    // happens from here.
                    // Response handling starts from here
                    // set the pointer to the beginning of the 
                    // memory stream to read
                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    // read the memory stream till the end
                    var response = await new StreamReader(memStream)
                        .ReadToEndAsync();
                    // write the response to the log object
                    log.Response = response;
                    log.ResponseCode = context.Response.StatusCode.ToString();
                    log.IsSuccessStatusCode = (
                        context.Response.StatusCode == 200 ||
                        context.Response.StatusCode == 201);
                    log.RespondedOn = DateTime.Now;

                    // since we have read till the end of the stream, 
                    // reset it onto the first position
                    memStream.Position = 0;

                    // now copy the content of the temporary memory 
                    // stream we have passed to the actual response body 
                    // which will carry the response out.
                    await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalRequest);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                // assign the response body to the actual context
                context.Response.Body = originalRequest;
            }
        }

    }
```